# Installation screen cut off when installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, display, 21.10

I have Ubuntu 21.10 with VirtualBox 6.1.26.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 21.10 in a virtual machine.
When I choose English as installation language, the keyboard selection screen looks like this:
[image]

As you see the lower edge is cut off - but it is still possible to go on with this.

However when I choose Japanese as installation language, the keyboard selection screen looks like this:
[image]
The buttons quit, back, continue are not visible.
The right edge is cut off as well as the lower edge.

The same happens on the following screens. How can I get a larger screen during installation?

EDIT:
The following happened when I followed @pasman pasmański's suggestion. The first few installation screens were ok but then suddenly the live system fell back to the low resolution:

[image]

But here the solution suggested in the second answer is working which helps to go through the remaining input screens.

EDIT2:

As @gronostaj suggested I tried to change the resolution once more, and then it goes on with this.

Comment: Did you tried higher screen resolution in guest machine ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtualbox sets screen resolution 800x600 which is below minimal requirements for Ubuntu. In installer press `Try Ubuntu` button, go to Settings->Displays->Resolution and select 1600x900 or more. Then you may continue installation.

Comment: I did not know that you can install while running the live system. It works perfectly!

Comment: I accepted your solution too fast. It works for the first few screens but when it asks whether to overwrite the existing system the display is refreshed and comes back in the low resolution - see screenshot in my edited question.

Comment: @muclux Have you tried changing it again?

Comment: @gronostaj I did not think of that (shame on me). But now I tried to set the screen resolution once more and it works!

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to disable kscreen in Autostarts. This is what reset the display resolution to something too low.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a bug of great glossy cool Yaru theme. It uses vertical space very effective, no doubt.

About the installer window - you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to move its window by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is actually to drag the window. I just had the same issue and thought it was impossible to get to "continue" as the screen was half cut off.. turns out this is a window and you can just click and drag it over to finish.